# ServiceLoader not finding Plugin

Tags: java, jar, serviceloader

I have a ServiceLoader that tries to load anything that extends Plugin. It is not finding anything, even though I have the service file set up.

Source code (`com.otabi.firestar.pajamatale.plugin.loader.PluginFinder` is the class): https://github.com/firestar115/PajamaTale

The plugin: https://github.com/firestar115/PajamaTest

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't the Plugin show up and print "Test Kappa"?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How am I able to have JARs that aren't in my classpath show up in the ServiceLoader? @NicolasFilotto

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the `URLClassLoader` requires a `URL` for each `jar` that represents a `Plugin`. It is **not** enough to instantiate the class loader with the `URL` to the directory containing the `jar` files. So what you need to do:

```
    File[] pluginFiles = directory.listFiles((File dir, String name) -> name.endsWith(".jar"));
    List<URL> urlsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : pluginFiles) {
        try {
            urlsList.add(file.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urlsList.toArray(new URL[]{}), Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Then, the `ServiceLoader` will be able to find your plugins.

Comment: This truly is the answer you're looking for if you googled the issue and landed on this page! I tried the other option and as stated it's not enough to have just the directory, you need the jar

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of `URLClassLoader` to which you provide the url of the directories that contain your plugins with the context `ClassLoader` as parent ClassLoader (I mean `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`) and use `ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class, myURLClassLoader)` instead of `ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class)` that uses internally the context `ClassLoader` which is not enough in your case as your plugins are not in your classpath.

Something like:

```
ClassLoader myURLClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
    new URL[]{new File("plugins").toURI().toURL()}, 
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
);
ServiceLoader<Plugin> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class, myURLClassLoader);
```

Comment: So basically `ServiceLoader.load(new URLClassLoader("plugins/"))`?

Comment: yes this is the idea with the context classloader as parent classloader

Comment: For creating the URL do I use a `file://` protocol or just use the normal `plugin`?

Comment: you need an URL that you can get with new File("foo").toURI().toURL()

Comment: Can you provide a method example? (in the answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116117/discussion-between-moo-we-all-do-and-nicolas-filotto).